# Show up the Sum/Sub textbox only if the num1 or num2 are inserted

Tags: jquery

I found a way to get sum/sub of 2 numbers using jQuery here

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //this calculates values automatically 
    sum();
    $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
        sum();
    });
});

function sum() {
            var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
            var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
            var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
                document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
                document.getElementById('subt').value = result1;
            }
        }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/javedfiddle/s4j7vm37/

However, I want

```
<tr><td>Sum:</td><td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly /></td></tr>
```

is hidden when input is empty.

How to do that with css or jQuery?

Comment: You wanna blank the result when one of the inputs is empty ?

Comment: I want <tr><td>Sum:</td><td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly /></td></tr>
to be hidden when inputs are empty

Comment: Added an answer. See if that is what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 if (!isNaN(result)) {
     document.getElementById('sum').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('subt').style.display = 'block';
     document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
     document.getElementById('subt').value = result1;
}else{
     document.getElementById('sum').style.display = 'none';
     document.getElementById('subt').style.display = 'none';
}
```

With jQuery:

```
if (!isNaN(result)) {
     $('#sum').show();
     $('#subt').show();
     $('#sum').val(result);
     $('#sum').val(result1);;
}else{
     $('#sum').hide();
     $('#subt').hide();
}
```

Or if you want the entire lines to vanish and not just the result boxes, you may add an id to your `<tr>` and hide and show them as you wish.

```
<tr id="sumtr">  
<tr id="subttr">
```

and you may use `$("#sumtr").hide();` and `$("#subttr").hide();`

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //this calculates values automatically 
  sum();
  $("#num1, #num2").on("keydown keyup", function() {
    sum();
  });
});

function sum() {
  if ( ($("#num1").val().length != 0 ) && ($("#num2").val().length != 0 ) ){
      $("#sum, #subt").parent("td").parent("tr").show();
    }else{
      $("#sum, #subt").parent("td").parent("tr").hide();
  }
  var num1 = document.getElementById('num1').value;
  var num2 = document.getElementById('num2').value;
  var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
  var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
  if (!isNaN(result)) {
    document.getElementById('sum').value = result;
    document.getElementById('subt').value = result1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Num 1:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num1" id="num1" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Num 2:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="num2" id="num2" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Sum:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Subtract:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="subt" id="subt" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give tr element ID (you can get it without it, too, but this is faster):

```
<tr id="third-row"><td>Sum:</td><td><input type="text" name="sum" id="sum" readonly /></td></tr>
```

Hide it on page load, if needed:

```
#third-row {
  display:none;
}
```

And add two few lines in your code to show/hide it:

```
   function sum() {
            var num1 = $('#num1').val();
            var num2 = $('#num2').val();
            var result = parseInt(num1) + parseInt(num2);
            var result1 = parseInt(num2) - parseInt(num1);
            if (!isNaN(result)) {
           $('#third-row').show();
                $('#sum').val(result);
                $('#subt').val(result1);
            }
            else {
             $('#third-row').hide();
            }
        }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/s4j7vm37/267/